# Excel VBA Sorting with multiple keys and custom order

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have a table that needs sorting based on two columns: A and E.
Column A is numerical and the ascending order is the first criteria.
Column E has specific values, and I need it to be arranged in a specific order: PS,MS,RDS,ES,FS,PFS,TS,DS,DE,TE,PFE,FE,EE,RDE,ME,PE.

I thought this code below would work, but it's definitely not doing the trick with the custom order.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

```
With Listing.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("E1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        CustomOrder:="PS,MS,RDS,ES,FS,PFS,TS,DS,DE,TE,PFE,FE,EE,RDE,ME,PE"
    .SetRange Columns("A:M")
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: See the [`SortField.Key` property documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sortfield.key):  "Specifies the range that is currently being sorted on. Read-only."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Key:=Range("xx")` parameter should be the sorted column cells instead of the header cell.